# When trying to log in to Pokemon Go, it says to update. Then says its already Installed

Tags: pokemon-go

I am playing on my galaxy S6. Everything was working great until the other day.

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling the app entirely and then re-installing it from the Play Store.

The app will then be force-updated to the latest version.